# images that are not used in CSS files

Tags: css, browser

what happens to them? are they loaded by the browsers?

should I split my CSS files into more stylesheets, so only images the css/images that are used are loaded on the page?

Comment: you mean like images used for background images?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what the profiler shows you in Chrome?

Comment: I was going to recommend firebug, but I believe the images are not downloaded until you reference them in the html.  You can confirm this using chrome or ie or firebug developer tools.  as far as splitting the css, I would only do so if you have an excessively large css file, or you need to split it up for different css files for browser capability i.e. you have styles that are ie7 or ie 8 specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as people are saying the same thing I said in my comment I guess I should have added it as an answer.

I was going to recommend firebug, but I believe the images are not downloaded until you reference them in the html. You can confirm this using chrome or ie or firebug developer tools. as far as splitting the css, I would only do so if you have an excessively large css file, or you need to split it up for different css files for browser capability i.e. you have styles that are ie7 or ie 8 specific

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will only download images that are actually used on the page. So images that are specified in CSS as background images will not be downloaded unless that CSS rule is applied on the page.

Comment: Certainly a relieving answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebug or other similar programs to see what is loaded by the browser; however, I believe the answer is that since the DOM element is never created, the image is never requested from the server. No bandwidth or loading time is wasted (other than a few more bytes of CSS, but that shouldn't be too much overhead.)